# Calendar add behaviour

Tags: java, calendar

Want to get first day of the next week (next monday), but call to `getTime()` changes the Calendar object.

Please tell me the right way to get first day of the next week.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            final Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar( 2013, 5, 6 );
            cal.setFirstDayOfWeek( Calendar.MONDAY );
            //System.out.println( sdf.format( cal.getTime() ) );
            cal.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,  Calendar.MONDAY );
            System.out.println( sdf.format( cal.getTime() ) );  // 2013-06-06
            cal.add( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1 );
            System.out.println( sdf.format( cal.getTime() ) );  // 2013-06-13
        }
        {
            final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            final Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar( 2013, 5, 6 );
            cal.setFirstDayOfWeek( Calendar.MONDAY );
            System.out.println( sdf.format( cal.getTime() ) );  // 2013-06-06
            cal.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,  Calendar.MONDAY );
            System.out.println( sdf.format( cal.getTime() ) );  // 2013-06-03
            cal.add( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1 );
            System.out.println( sdf.format( cal.getTime() ) );  // 2013-06-10
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice example...

The `Calendar` is not easy to handle. You problem is the evaluation of the date.

The date of the `Calendar` is newly evaluated if you call e.g. `getTime()` or `add()`.

In the second (correct) example you call `getTime()` after setting the first day of the week and the calendar is set to `2013-06-06`. After that you change the day of the week and set the calendar new (via `getTime()`). Therefore it is now set to Monday.

In the first example you set the `Calendar` to the date and set the day of week. This leads to an invalid date (temporarily). `2013-06-06` is a Thursday and you set Monday. Now which one is the correct day of week? The `Calendar` implementation now chooses Thursday.

This is also [well documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) in the Javadoc. The section is named **Calendar Fields Resolution**.